# How work maxAge in Spring Kafka Factory Producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We are using transactional producers and sometimes we find ourselves in the situation where there is no traffic for more than 7 days, which leads to the loss of transactional id metadata. The next write after this time always causes an error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id.
```

workaround for now is to restart all instances in Kubernetes.

Reviewing the documentation, I see that in version 2.5.8 a new property 'maxAge' has been added, which must be less than 7 days to be able to refresh the metadata on the broker side. I was testing and there is no way to make it work as expected.

I have set up a demo project to simulate the behavior, except for some error on my part, maxAge does not refresh metadata before the time of:

```
transactional.id.expiration.ms
```

Versions used:

1. confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest - Kafka 3.4
2. Spring Boot 3.1.5 JDK 17
3. Kafka Clients 3.4.1
4. Spring Kafka 3.0.12
5. Spring Stream Binder Kafka 4.0.4

The transaction metada is forced to expire in 10 seconds.

```
  KAFKA_TRANSACTIONAL_ID_EXPIRATION_MS: 10000
  KAFKA_PRODUCER_ID_EXPIRATION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 100
  KAFKA_PRODUCER_ID_EXPIRATION_MS: 10000
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_ABORT_TIMED_OUT_TRANSACTION_CLEANUP_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_REMOVE_EXPIRED_TRANSACTION_CLEANUP_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
```

Set the maxAge to 7 seconds, with the expectation that it will refresh before 10 seconds to gain an additional 10 seconds:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer producerFactoryCustomizer() {
        return producerFactory -> producerFactory.setMaxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(7));
    }

}
```

Test Controller to producer message on demand

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    private AtomicInteger semaphore = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public void sequentialSimple() {
            streamBridge.send("sendTestData-out-0", "testMessage_" + semaphore.getAndIncrement());
    }

}
```

I expect to never encounter the InvalidPidMappingException, but I always see it.

```
2023-11-19T13:22:57.234+01:00 DEBUG 28648 --- [fix_localhost-0] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-transactionTestPrefix_localhost-0, transactionalId=transactionTestPrefix_localhost-0] Transition from state COMMITTING_TRANSACTION to error state ABORTABLE_ERROR

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id.
```

If I don't handle the ABORTABLE_ERROR (AfterRollbackProcessor) or DLQ, I also lose messages. What am I doing wrong?

Github Demo Project: https://github.com/Fonexn/kafkaMaxAgeTesting

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

Set `maxAge` to each binder in this way, example:

```
@Bean
KafkaTransactionManager customKafkaTransactionManager() {
    KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafka = (KafkaMessageChannelBinder)this.binderFactory.getBinder("kafka1", MessageChannel.class);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> producerFactory = (DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]>) kafka.getTransactionalProducerFactory();

    producerFactory.setMaxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

    return new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxAge` does not refresh the metadata. When a transactional producer is retrieved from the cache, if the `maxAge` has been exceeded, the producer is closed and we examine the next one in the cache. This continues until a young producer is found or the cache is empty. If all the producers in the cache are too old, a new producer is created.

See `createTransactionalProducer()` and `expire()`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Gary. If I understand correctly, to fix this behavior, I need to recreate all producers before the metadata expires on the broker side. For this, I can use createTransactionalProducer(). However, how can I determine the exact moment to do this (some schedule cron?) or capture this event in Spring? For now the best workaround is restart all instances every week.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything; the check will be made the next time you try to send something. The `KafkaTemplate` will attempt to get a producer from the cache, and the above algorithm will kick in.

Comment: As you can see in the demo project above, if I do nothing and leave it with the default configuration, the Transaction ID expires and on the next write, the producer returns an InvalidPidMappingException. It doesn't do what you're saying. Do I need to do something to avoid this error, or am I not understanding correctly and have something misconfigured? Sorry

Comment: I didn't notice you were using spring-cloud-stream - please add that tag in future. The binder doesn't use Spring Boot's auto configured producer factory (to which the customizer is applied). You can get a reference to the binder's transactional producer factory and set the `maxAge` there. Get a reference to the binder from the `BinderFactory` - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-transactional-binder You should also open a new feature request issue to add `maxAge` to the binder properties.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Now it is working as expected. Issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2856